# Time limit exceeded in bubble sort

Tags: arrays, sorting, bubble-sort

**Problem-To sort array in ascending order**
**Algorithm used-Bubble sort**
**Error-Time limit exceeded**
**Compiler-ideone online editor /Codeblocks**
What could be the possible alternative for this?

```
int a[5];
int i,t,j;
for(i=0;i<=4;i++)  //for initialising the elements
 {
 printf("Enter 5 numbers");
 scanf("%d",&a[i]);
 }

for(j=0;j<5;i++)  //for sorting 
{

  for(i=0;i<5;i++)
  {
  if(a[i]>a[i+1])
    {
  t=a[i+1];
  a[i+1]=a[i];
  a[i]=t;
    }
  }
 }
for(i=0;i<=4;i++)  //for printing the sorted array
{

   printf("%d\n",a[i]);
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- Your loop:

  ```
  for(j=0;j<5;i++)  //for sorting
  ```

should say j++, so it should be

```
    for(j=0;j<5;j++)
```

- Your second loop:

  ```
  for(i=0;i<5;i++)
  ```

should be

```
    for(i=0;i<4;i++)
```